# Do identical imports in different modules "stack" in memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Suppose I have 2 files `first.py`, `second.py` and both files import the same module, lets say `requests`. If `first.py` imports `second.py` would `requests` be stacked twice in memory, or would python use some kind of caching system to import `requests` once and use it in both files.

Comment: No, they are cached in `sys.modules`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is best answered by the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), not by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you `import` a module, functions and so on, the first thing `Python` will do is look up the name `request` in [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules), so this works as a cache of all modules that have been previously imported. If the name is not found, then `Python` will check if module is part of the built-in modules and finally it will search for it in a list of directories defined by [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). Hope this can help you :)